# How to open new android XML page with button in Android?

Tags: android, xml, button

I want to make a app that has buttons that open new `XML` pages for the user to view. I'm new to this and from the little I found, I think I need something like this but I'm not sure and could be wrong:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

and

```
setContentView(R.layout.page1);
```

But I'm not sure of the imports and also if anyone knows on good tutorials that I could follow to learn more on coding Android apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below code in your main actiivty

```java
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Create a new activity name NewActivity.java
 in its onCreate method add the xml you want by using below statement.

```
setContentView(R.layout.page1);
```

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing is fine with the `setContentView(R.layout.page1);`, but you need to set a button listener for that button:

```java
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

myButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.page1);
    }
});
```